# How to make a table horizontally scrollable and the tbody vertically scrollable

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an html table with bootstrap class table-responsive. While scrolling horizontally, I want the whole table to scroll but while doing it vertically, I want only the tbody to scroll. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this.

HTML code for the table:

```
<div class="table-container">
  //table goes in here
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.table-container {
  width: //your choice;
  height: //your choice;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

CSS for the tbody:

```
tbody {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```